# Manual IP Routes Getting Disabled (by Network Manager?)

Tags: debian, routing, debian-jessie, networkmanager

I have a situation with a Debian Jessie server where I am manually creating an IP route, and after the first time I use it, it stops working.

On my network, I have 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 subnets which are mostly isolated. However, in my Cisco RV325 router, I allow an exception for 192.168.2.* traffic to 192.168.1.* hosts (but not vice versa). This works fine for all other clients (MacOS, Win10) on my 192.168.2.* subnet, without additional configuration.

However, on my 192.168.2.* Debian server, I cannot reach 192.168.1.* hosts. So, I tried manually adding a route (on the Debian box) via

```
root@debian$ route -v 
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
default         router          0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

root@debian$ route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1 metric 1

root@debian$ route -v
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router          0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     router          255.255.255.0   UG    1      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

At this point, I can successfully connect to a HTTP host on the other virtual LAN:

```
root@debian$ telnet 192.168.1.24 80
Trying 192.168.1.24...
Connected to 192.168.1.24.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I can manually ask for a webpage, for example, and the content gets returned. The connection is then closed, and any **subsequent** attempt fails:

```
Trying 192.168.1.24...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

The `route -v` still shows the route I added, but it's essentially unusable. What is going wrong here? Is some other piece of software likely actively shutting down what it thinks are illegitimate routes?

I have seen [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/417868), and tried all three current answers, none of which worked for me.

I tried disabling Network Manager altogether, but that broke my default route, which is a much more serious problem. So, I am posing this question as "**how to add a route to another subnet on a system with Network Manager**"? Manually, or automatically on boot, are both fine.

## Update

Per questions below, iptables shows:

```
root@debian$ iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5376 packets, 1052K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2490  184K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3041 packets, 1187K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   13  1016 REJECT     all  --  *      *       154.8.139.43         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       192.99.122.172       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 2477  183K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

None of those IPs seem relevant. Before posing the question, I did try disabling the fail2ban service, with no effect.

`ip addr` on the debian host shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:55:db:36:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:55:db:36:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.34/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Note: I do have a second NIC (eth2) on the machine, but it's unplugged and DOWN. Not present in routing table.

Comment: Please use `ip addr` and `ip route` on Linux instead of the outdated route/ifconfig tools, which in many cases can be found omitting critical information.

Comment: @grawity, thanks for the tip. Replaced ifconfig output in edit above.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost likely not a routing issue on your client - rather it is likely to be a firewall issue or issue on the server.

My guess would be incorrect routing on the server  due to an incorrect netmask there  (Maybe 255.255.0.0 which is fairly common), combined with reverse path filtering on the client.  You can check this by, for example, disabling reverse path filtering on the client with a command like echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter - but the solution is to fix the networking on the server because the packets are not being sent back to the router.   (This may also involve allowing "RELATED" traffic back in the router).

If that fails, Look at the iptables rules to see if it is being blocked there - you can see these by typing iptables -vnL.  (You may want to post these for us to have a look at).  It could also be related to the router, conceivably even a NAT related issue.

Generally, where possible, the next step is to do some packet sniffing to see what is leaving the computer and what is being received by the web server and vv.   You can use tcpdump (in a seperate window and then make a request) with a command like

`tcpdump -n -i eth1 tcp src or dst 192.168.1.24`

(I note that the route command you have added is redundant - and I suspect you misunderstand its purpose.  This is not the cause of your issue though.  If the problem relates to Reverse path filtering, you might be able to bypass the router alltogether with a command like *route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1*)

Comment: I do get that adding the route *should* be redundant. The default route should pick up anything in 192.168.1.x, right? I only tried it because it wasn't working originally. Can you clarify which machine you're calling the "client"? Is it my Debian box (in 192.168.2.x)? A reason I'm skeptical that it's a problem on the 192.168.1.x server side is that, as I said, this all works fine from other 192.168.2.x hosts.

Comment: The `route add -net 192.168.1.0 net mask 255.255.255.0 eth1` does not work, BTW. I'll look into installing tcpdump. I'll put `iptables` output in an edit above ...

Comment: Here are the [IP settings on 192.168.1.24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZNI.png).  Consumer device w/ built-in web server. Nothing more configurable. The router 192.168.1.1 is the same device as 192.168.2.1. These are **virtual** LANs.

Comment: That precise tcpdump command isn't valid for me, but removing the TCP protocol filter, `tcpdump -n -i eth1 src or dst 192.168.1.24` yields only this, repeating: `19:20:55.019622 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.24 tell 192.168.2.34, length 28`. 2.34 is my Debian "client". Anyway, this is a problem at the IP layer, so I'm not sure what TCP traffic would reveal here.

Comment: Why are ARP requests being generated for an IP address on another network? What does "ifconfig" show?   Is the netmask on your Debian client correctly set?

Comment: I updated the question with the ifconfig output